# How use raise notice in nested and sub-function?

Tags: postgresql, functions, debugging

I'm using PgAdmin to create multiple pgsql functions.
I'm beginner on this environment.
I'm using 'raise notice' to help me for debugging phase.

I have two functions with 'raise notice' statement.
The first function calls the second function.

I can show the 'raise notice' statement for the first function.
I can't show the 'raise notice' statement for the second function. In place, the console show blank lines for each 'raise notice' that should be shown.

*Function 1 - Example :*

```
raise notice 'Function 1 executing';    -- This raise notice works
PERFORM public.function_2();
```

*Function 2 - Example :*

```
raise notice 'Function 2 is now running';   -- This raise notice doesn't work
```

Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I have tested the following with PG 12.2 and with psql CLI:

```
show client_min_messages;
client_min_messages 
---------------------
notice
(1 row) 
create or replace function f2 () returns text
as
$$
declare
begin
 raise notice 'Function 2 is now running';
 return 'f2: OK';
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
create or replace function f1 () returns text
as
$$
declare
begin
 raise notice 'Function 1 executing';
 perform f2();
 return 'f1: OK';
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
select f1();
psql:t2f.sql:27: NOTICE:  Function 1 executing
psql:t2f.sql:27: NOTICE:  Function 2 is now running
   f1   
--------
 f1: OK
(1 row)
```

Comment: Make sure `client_min_messages` is correctly set and not modified by your code. Are you writing something else to standard output ? Is there any message in database log ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for responding,

I never needed to change any parameter of PostGre server or PgAdmin. So, I don't know them well.
I'm not sure about my PgAdmin version, the 'About' form say 1.20 (?!)

My client_min_messages is like you and my code doesn' modify it.

The result in the messages panel is a little different than you, like that :

NOTICE:  Function 1 executing

[Blank line]

Total duration of request execution :23 ms.
1 line recovered.

There are [Blank line] as many times I call the function 2.

Comment: can you try to test it using psql CLI interface ? It it works it means it's a pgAdmin issue.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, what is 'psql CLI interface'. I'm only working in PgAdmin Desktop to create and launch my functions. Is it PSQL Console ?

Comment: PG Version is 9.4

Comment: yes it's PSQL Console (psql.exe on Windows - psql executable on Linux). I recommend also to upgrade pgAdmin to a more recent version.

Comment: Ok, I go for installing last version and try it. The psql console generate an error on the PERFORM statement (invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xab), if i remove the PERFORM, there is no error.

Comment: Working on PG11 (another PC) ! But not working on PG9.4, so strange. If you have tips with this old 9.4 version, i'm interesting. I continue my dev on PG11 or 12, thank you.

Comment: The above script is also OK with PG 9.4.26 using psql CLI.

Comment: In psql CLI, I don't understand why but the "raise notice" line in the second function generates 'invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xab'. If i remove this line, there is no error.